# Java Web Form валидация

Tags: веб-программирование, java, framework

Есть такая задача: требуется сделать html формы и их обработчики для поиска и добавления в таблицу с ~100 разными колонками. С разной валидацией и т.д. Есть ли какой-то веб фреймворк, который может сильно облегчить эту задачу? Желательно без обилия xml.

Answer (score 1):

любой подойдет, spring, mvc, tapestry..